# This is the continuing of the previous message because it was refused as spam

Tags: linux, sendmail

---authInfo---

```
AuthInfo: "U:root" "I:info@***domain***" "P:mypasswd"
```

When I send an email with:

```
mail -s "subject" myemailaddress </tmp/work
```

I get this in /var/log/maillog

```
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: 3A1HB5Ro007845: SMTP outgoing connect on [ip***]
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS: ClientCertFile missing
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS: ClientKeyFile missing
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS: CACertPath missing
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS: CACertFile missing
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS: CRLFile missing
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS=client, init=1
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS=client, start=ok
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS=client, info: fds=11/10, err=2
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS=client, info: fds=11/10, err=2
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS=client, get_verify: 20 get_peer: 0x861b488
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS=client, relay=smtp.office365.com, version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS=client, cert-subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft+20Corporation/CN=outlook.com, cert-issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert+20Inc/CN=DigiCert+20Cloud+20Services+20CA-1, verifymsg=unable to get local issuer certificate
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: STARTTLS=read, info: fds=11/10, err=2
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** last message repeated 4 times
Nov  1 18:11:05 ****host*** sendmail[7847]: 3A1HB5Ro007845: to=<mymailto>, ctladdr=<tbred@****host***> (501/501), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=120501, relay=smtp.office365.com [52.97.215.114], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred
```

As I look at the logfile, I see a message about a certificate. Do I need a certificate.
My client used msmtp to send an email without certificate and this worked

---configuration msmtp---

```
host smtp.office365.com
protocol smtp
auth on
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_certcheck on
#tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
from info@***domain***
port 587
user info@***domain***
password mypasswd
```

Comment: Your [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1147023/centos-5-trying-to-use-sendmail-to-send-mail-using-the-smtp-microsoft-server-of) was not refused as spam, it was closed as off topic because CentOS 5 has been end of life since 2017 and we follow best business practices here. Reposting your question won't change that.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
auth on
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_certcheck on
```

requires a server certificate with a trust chain anchor on the client.